# A symfony2 ACL for many users

Tags: symfony, security, acl

I have an Order entity which has a buyer (User entity) and a seller (User entity).

I would like this order to be visible only by the 2 users (buyer and seller) via Symfony2 ACL.

I have done many tests but without success. HELP PLEASE ! 
This is the script below :

```
       // creating the ACL
        $aclProvider = $this->get('security.acl.provider');
        $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($order);
        try {
          $acl = $aclProvider->findAcl($objectIdentity);
        } catch(\Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Exception\AclNotFoundException $e) {
          $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);
        }

        // mask builder permissions
        $maskBuilder = new MaskBuilder();
        $maskBuilder->add('view')
                    ->add('edit');
        $mask = $maskBuilder->get();

        // security identity for the seller
        $securityIdentitySeller = new UserSecurityIdentity($order->getSeller(), "ACMEUserBundle\Entity\User");
        $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentitySeller, $mask);

        // security identity for the buyer
        $securityIdentityBuyer = new UserSecurityIdentity($order->getBuyer(), "ACMEUserBundle\Entity\User");
        $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentityBuyer, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);

        // update the acl
        $aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
```

========================================================================
Unfortunately, this script creates 2 ACEs in database with the same user (order seller)

Answer (score 0):

Your situation sounds almost exactly like the example presented in the [Symfony Cookbook section on ACL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html). That example is about a blogger wanting only the author of a comment on his blog to be able to edit his or her own comments, in addition to the blogger himself or herself.  Other commenters should not be able to edit other commenters comments.  The only real difference between this example and your situation is edit permission versus viewing permission. You can handle the particulars of that in a number of ways once you have the needed filtering of your ACL as seen in detail in the cookbook.

Comment: I have edited my question with some script to more understand me